# Find the number of ways to launch satellites in space?

Tags: permutations, combinations

**Question: Let X= {S<sub>1</sub>,S<sub>2</sub>,S<sub>3</sub>,S<sub>4</sub>,S<sub>5</sub>} and Y = {L<sub>1</sub>,L<sub>2</sub>,L<sub>3</sub>} be the sets of satellites and launching sites respectively. If each site launches at least one satellite, find the number of ways to launch satellites in the space.**

My solution:
L<sub>1</sub> have choice of 5 satellites
L<sub>2</sub> have choice of 4 satellites
L<sub>3</sub> have choice of 3 satellites
Remaining two satellites can choose any station among 3
Hence my answer is 5*4*3*3*3. But the answer is wrong.

Comment: It is wrong because you paid special importance to which of the satellites was the "*first choice*" satellite for each launching pad when that doesn't matter.  Having picked $S_1$ for $L_1$, then picked $S_2$ for $L_2$, then $S_3$ for $L_3$ and then picked $L_1$ for both $S_4$ and $S_5$ is considered the same but counted separately than having picked $S_4$ for $L_1$, $S_2$ for $L_2$, then $S_3$ for $L_3$ and then picked $L_1$ for both $S_1$ and $S_5$.

Comment: For a correct approach, use inclusion-exclusion or use stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768474/4-element-subset-of-1-6-that-includes-1-or-4-and-2-or-5-and/3768514#3768514

Comment: @YJT did you paste the wrong link?  That seems completely unrelated.

Comment: It's a different question but the same common mistake to which I refer in bold.